# Which Legend of Zelda game does this Link with the white cap belong to?

Tags: game-identification, legend-of-zelda-series

I installed a *Legend of Zelda* theme for my computer, and one picture drew my attention.

[image: 'The Legend of Zelda: 25th Anniversary', showing several different images of Link, including the one in question where Link has white hair and white eyes, and wears a white cap]

I am somewhat familiar which game each Link comes from, but I am not able to figure out which one the Link on the top-right is from, the Link with the white eyes and white cap - I have not seem him before. Which Zelda game is he from?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It looks like [Fierce Deity Link](http://zeldawiki.org/Fierce_Deity), a form Link can transform into using the Fierce Deity's Mask in Majora's mask. In addition to the white hair and cap this form also has three blue gems under the collar that you can see in your picture.

[image: Fierce Deity Link]
Image from zeldawiki.org

Comment: I didn't know Link could even get more BA looking. Thanks!

Comment: @Wondercricket, only with the Feirce Deity Mask, which requires you to collect *all* masks. It's essentially the reward for (almost) 100% completion in Majora's Mask. If only *all* games had such an awesome 100% completion reward...

Comment: Thanks, now I have a strong desire to go back and play Majora's Mask and collect all the masks...

Comment: @forgivenson - It *is* pretty awesome, but it's only actually usable during boss fights.

Comment: Image from the actual game: http://i.imgur.com/nD56oup.jpg

Comment: Now I have to go play Majora's mask again...thanks.. lol

Comment: @Bobson There is a trick to use it outside of boss fights! It requires events in the waning hours of the third day, so you can’t use it for long, and there’s tons of areas Fierce Deity Link can’t fit in, but you can do it.

Answer (score 12):

That looks like the [Fierce Deity](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Fierce_Deity), which Link can transform into by using the [Fierce Deity's Mask](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Fierce_Deity's_Mask) in Majora's Mask.

[image: Fierce Deity Image]